# Make a simple search algorithm more elegant

Tags: javascript, algorithm, underscore.js, ecmascript-5

```
// temp data
var array = [1,2,function() { }, 3, function() { }];
var cb = function() { console.log("foo"); }


var found = false;
console.log(_.map(array, function(val) {
    if (_.isFunction(val) && !found) {
        return found = true, _.compose(cb, val);
    } 
    return val;
}));
```

This loops through the array and turns the first function it finds into a composed function.

I hate that `found = false` variable / counter. How do I get rid of it?

As an algorithm.

```
let found be 0
map value in array
    if value satisfies condition and found is 0
        let found be 1
        return mutate(value)
    else
        return value
```

**Update**

Using a for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (_.isFunction(array[i])) {
        array[i] = _.compose(cb, array[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

[`_.map`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#map), [`_`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/), [`_.isFunction`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#isFunction), [`_.compose`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#compose)

Comment: Isn't there a 'break;' statement in the language? I would use that to get out of the loop.

Comment: @PeteWilson that's what I was thinking. Then I need a normal for loop rather then an enumeration though. I think I'll refactor it with a for.

Comment: Does wrapping the loop in `console.log` do anything here? The loop doesn't return a value - running this in the Chrome console just outputs `undefined`.

Comment: @nrabinowitz the map does something. The for loop just manipulates the array. The map returns the altered array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming short-circuit evaluation: (which I promptly bastardise)

```
let found be 0
for each value in array
    if value satisfies condition and found is 0 and let found be not found
        let value be mutate(value)
```

edited problem, edited answer:

```
let found be 0
for each value in array
  return ( value satisfies condition and found is 0 and let found be not found ) ? mutate(value) : value
```

Comment: I choose this one because it's less lines >_>

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this answers your need for elegance, but it seems to me like `_.each()` or `forEach` is wasting extra loops after the item has been found. With a traditional `for` or `while` loop, you could call `break` at that point. Not a big deal with a small array, but it could become an issue for a larger array or a complex condition check. If you want to avoid the constant `array[x]` references, you could get a little fancier than the obvious option:

```
for (var val, x=0; x<array.length; val=array[++x]) {
    if (_.isFunction(val)) {
        array[x] = _.compose(cb, val);
        break;
    }
}
```